# I have a "home" partition, now how do I get my system to put my files there?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, home-directory

When setting up my system, I created a partition and mounted it as "/home", so I assumed my documents would land there, but they do not.
When I open and select my user name, Levde, I get a standard user file system.

[image]

When I select "Documents", because I have used it, I find the directory I called "machine&software". Then I go to "home", listed as a device, and what I find there is the "lost & found" file, but not my "machine&software" directory. So I know that my effort to define this device as the location for my "/Home" directory failed. Here is an image of Gparted showing mount point information and how much space I allocated to each partition.

[image]

I don't know how to assign "/home" status to my "/home" partition, and at this point, how to move the standard document template from the root directory to a new mount point. As of now, the folder "Levde" is found in the root directory under "home", where it should be (root home levde). Here is an image that shows  where my "/home" partition is mounted:

[image]

Across the top you will see Ubuntu Studio's path rendering "[root icon] media levde Home." Obviously when I set up my partitioning and instructed the installer to mount this partition as "/home", that was not sufficient for it to BE /home. I don't think I installed it as "root media levde home", but that is where it landed.

Considering these thoughts, I thought "perhaps I need to change its mount point!" I unmounted it in gparted, but gparted would not allow me to mount it again, anywhere, so that strategy didn't work, this time.

In comments I was asked to report "cat /etc/fstab". I report this as an image file:

[image]

Comment: Please add the outputs of `cat /etc/fstab` in your post. It is very likely just a matter of adjusting the mount point. Home directories always go to /home/$username, you cannot just mount them anywhere and expect the system to find them.

Comment: Installer does not automatically use a partition, you create in advance. You have to use Something Else and either choose(change) the partition as /home or create a new partition as /home. Default install is only / (root). And an ESP if UEFI. You may want to copy any data you have saved to the internal /home and then mount separate /home as /home. Detailed procedure: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: On the Ubuntu Community help wiki, I found a page called "Home/Moving". It is detailed and yet thoughtful.

Comment: On the Ubuntu Community help wiki, I found a page called "Home/Moving". It is detailed and yet thoughtful. Oldfred - I guess this is the page you referred to. Sebastian, thank you for your input. I crashed my previous system trying to follow instructions in linked web page above when I was denied permission to alter fstab, I changed permissions, which then left my system incapable of booting. I couldn't figure out how to restore native permissions. My fault but that is where these instructions got derailed.

Comment: Serafim - I guess "bragging" is too strong a word but having a separate partition for /home is tauted as a possible advantage. Ever since I started using Windows 35 years ago and had to reinstall my system every few days, I have preferred to have my user files on a separate partition - have seen it as good computer hygiene.

Comment: thank you everyone for commenting. I think my responsibility now is to return to the above named instructions and attempt to follow them more carefully. The tips you provided are reflected in those instructions.

Comment: The recipe found on the referred page must be slightly altered as you have already mounted `/media` on `/dev/sda4`. It might be better to copy your files in `/home/levde` to a USB stick.

Comment: Your screenshot of `cat /etc/fstab` does not contain the relevant parts, it seems to be cut off at the bottom. At least it doesn't show a mounted home partition anywhere.

Comment: Sebastian, I reported what the command gave me. Maybe the problem is that "fstab" isn't complete (I tried to edit it, maybe I messed it up.)

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of texts in the terminal. Rather copy the text and paste it directly into your question and format the copied text as `code` by using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so if I understand you problem correctly, you have a separate partition on `/dev/sda4` that you want to be Home, and which is now mounted on `/media` instead. You will have to tell the system to mount it in the right place, but before that copy everything you have right now in your current Home directory into your new Home partition so you can switch seamlessly afterwards without losing any configurations you may have made already.

### Step 1 - Copy Home directory

It seems that your new Home partition on `/media/levde/Home` is empty right now. Copy all files, including hidden files and subdirectories, from `/home/levde` to `/media/levde/Home`.

### Step 2 - Add Home partition to fstab

Next you need to tell the system which partition to mount to `/home`. To do that, open `/etc/fstab` in an editor of your choice (gedit, nedit, kate...) as superuser, e.g. via `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.

In another terminal, enter `lsblk -f /dev/sda4` to get the UUID of your new Home partition.

In the fstab you're editing, add a line at the end like this:

`UUID=$UUID_you_just_found_out   /home/levde   ext4   defaults   0   2`

and replace `$UUID_you_just_found_out` with the UUID that `lsblk` gave you.

Save the file and exit the editor.

### Step 3 - Reboot

Now all you need to do is reboot, and the new partition should be mounted under /home/levde. To verify, do a `lsblk` in a terminal and check where `/dev/sda4`is mounted.

### Notes

Note 1: It is worth mentioning that the content in the original `/home/levde` directory is not gone, it is just "covered" by the mounted new partition. If the partition is unmounted again, the original home partition will reappear.

Note 2: This procedure only copies your current user's home directory to the new partition. Any additional new user would end up on your system's root partition again.

Comment: perhaps you could add a command to the first step in your answer like the one given in oldfred's link `sudo rsync -aXS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.`

Comment: You may want to make sure that the whole `levde` from inside `/home/` is copied to the destination `/media/levde/Home`. So that after copying you have `/media/levde/Home/levde`. One way of doing it is as shown by @db429 above.

Comment: Since I recommend mounting it to `/home/levde` in the end, you don't want to have a subdirectory `/levde` on your partition, or you end up with `/home/levde/levde`.

Comment: I am going to do my best to study and use these instructions. Please be patient as I am easily confused by the numerous details. At this moment my system is busy copying files. (about 20 hours so far.) I will try to sort out what it all means and comment when I have done so. I am grateful for the time you have given to give me help.